# Plotting a function on a date axis

Tags: plot, graph, openoffice-calc

In one column, I have a series of dates. In another column, I have a series of values. I'd like to plot the values on the y axis, and the dates on the x axis -- but I'd like a proper scale on the x axis, as some of the dates are distant by hundreds of days while some are only a week apart. So the points shouldn't be equally horizontally spaced from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XY (Scatter) chart type, which will display the dates proportionally. The other chart types (Column, Bar, Area, Line) will all display points equally spaced horizontally.